# Netflix Atlas says "Subscriptions not enabled" on start of application of Spring-Boot 2.0.1

Tags: java, spring, atlas, micrometer

When I start my app made with Spring Boot 2.0.1, I always see this info log:

`2018-05-08 16:36:09.409  INFO 18737 --- [localhost-startStop-1] c.netflix.spectator.atlas.AtlasRegistry  : started collecting metrics every PT10S reporting to http://localhost:7101/api/v1/publish
2018-05-08 16:36:09.410  INFO 18737 --- [localhost-startStop-1] c.netflix.spectator.atlas.AtlasRegistry  : common tags: {}
2018-05-08 16:36:09.410  INFO 18737 --- [localhost-startStop-1] c.netflix.spectator.atlas.AtlasRegistry  : subscriptions are not enabled`

What does `subscriptions are not enabled` means? What does it changes? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to a somewhat hidden feature of Atlas that allows you to subscribe to particular metrics. It can be safely ignored. Regular publishing appears to be enabled.